# Firestore Queries Swift 4 for range

Tags: swift, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

i want to ask a question related to firestore queries swift. I have firestore structure as below:

[image]

currently i develop a search system, where user can filter `min` and `max` persons per `team`. below are the queries for `.collection("team")`

```
Firestore.firestore().collection("team")
.whereField("min", isGreaterThanOrEqualTo : filterMin)
.whereField("max", isLessThanOrEqualTo : filterMax)
```

Expected: if user place `filterMin` = 0 and `filterMax` = 600 data for `team1` and `team2` will displayed, if user place `filterMin` = 3 and `filterMax` = 500, only data for `team2` will displayed.

But the problem is if i using the code above, i got an error as below

> 'Invalid Query. All where filters with an inequality (lessThan,
>   lessThanOrEqual, greaterThan, or greaterThanOrEqual) must be on the
>   same field. But you have inequality filters on 'min' and 'max''

I have already read the documentation, but it seems does not help me much. I am still new in swift development and firebase. thanks for helping me.

Comment: Basically, `Cloud Firestore` does not allow you do that level of filtering at present.  A workaround may be to run the first `.whereField` query, and then once you have your documents, filter your array for the second query.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Cloud Firestore does not at present allow you to do multiple inequality filters. A workaround may be to run the first .whereField query, and then once you have your documents, filter your array for the second query.

```
    Firestore.firestore().collection("team")
    .whereField("min", isGreaterThanOrEqualTo : filterMin)
        .getDocuments { (snapshot, error) in
            if let snapshot = snapshot {
                for document in snapshot.documents {
                    let data = document.data()

                    //parse your data into an array of teams
                }
            }

            let filteredTeams = teams.filter { $0.max < filterMax }    
    }
```

Comment: hi, thanks for helping me, i have parse my data into an array. now, what should i do with constant `filteredTeams`

Comment: `filteredTeams` should contain the array of teams that you were trying to originally query for.  Those with a min > filterMin & max < filterMax.

Comment: Firestore limitations on querying are very annoying. This makes Google Firestore unusable for a large project

Answer (score 0):

You cannot have an inequality operator on multiple fields, a field in your being being either min or max. Firestore only supports one inEquality operator (<, >, <=, >=) and then as many eqaulity operators (==) as you want.

You can read more about it under 'Compound Queries' [here](https://cloud.google.com/firestore/docs/query-data/queries)